# Perforce changelist does not show any files

Tags: perforce, p4v

Using P4V 2009.2.
I have used P4Win in the past, but this is a new setup for me.
The problem is that the files I have checked out disappear from the changelists, so I cannot check them in.

To reproduce:

1. Check out a file, make a change to it.
2. Go to the 'pending changelist' tab.
3. There will be a + sign on the default changelist.
4. Click on the plus, or on the changelist line, the plus will disappear, there will be nothing in the changelist.
5. Try to check the file in by right-click on the file itself, the changelist dialog will show up but NO files are listed.
6. You can transfer the file to a new changelist, the same thing happens.
7. Looking at the file in the 'checked out by' window does correctly show the changelist number & description.

Comment: Thanks for your help - the files did show when I looked at the changelist via the batch commands.  Something was not working in the view.   I took everything out of that workspace, deleted the workspace and basically restarted from the beginning.  Now it's working correctly.

Comment: In my case I had "Show only pending changelists with shelved files" checked. Discovered that after I tried some of the solutions here.

Answer (score 3):

It sometimes happens to me, and what I normally do is change workspace and then change back again. Not sure if there is an easier way to get it to realise the files are checked out.

Answer (score 1):

the only thing I can imagine is that you are looking at a different client workspace. Notice that the "Pending Changes" tab has a filter on the top, where you can separately filter for folder/files, user and workspace. Maybe the filter is set to something so that it doesn't match the client workspace where you have actually checked out the file.
Good luck,
Henrik

Answer (score 1):

You may get this if the perforce server has not been upgraded. Old versions of P4D have this error: http://kb.perforce.com/article/1167/opened-files-missing-in-default-changelist

If that is not an option, use p4Win.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jhwist,sounds like your looking at a different client spec.
P4V is a bit confusing on this front, IMO and I personally prefer P4 Win but to check, open up a command prompt and type `p4 changes -s pending -c YOURCLIENTSPEC` - chances are that the changes you think you have aren't in your current clientspec

Answer (score 0):

This can happen sometimes and in my experience it is a refresh issue with p4v.  Often simply closing the pending tab or reopening p4v solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the pending List has over 4000 files, (due to eclipse created so many files after mvn tasks) so none of them are shown. I created a different pending list, then cleared all contents, then moved the files to the new change list. Then it is appearing in the new change list.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the file directly in the correctly mapped client folder (i.e. your current workspace). You will see the changelist for sure. As jhwist mentioned clear filters if any and choose your current workspace (since you may have many)